# How to upgrade the deployed meteor server with old user data

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, meteor

Oops, just found another guy's commit, the data was delete by him:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    partner_class.remove({});
    partner_class.remove({});
    partner_photos.remove({});
    Posts.remove({});
```

I've already deployed my website on meteor, then I need update it.
If I simply use meteor deploy travellers.meteor.com, the old data will be reset.
How to keep the old data when update meteor website?

Forget to say, I'm using GroundDB for offline capability.

in main.js(placed in the top directly)

```
Posts = new GroundDB('posts');
```

Template:

```
<template name="reply_blackboard_post">
    <div class="footbar">
        <form class="new-reply">
            <table style="width: 100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="text" type="text" name="comment" placeholder="说点什么" /></td>
                    <td style="width: 110px; text-align:right;">
                        <img class="good" src="/blackboard/fsdf.png" />
                        <input class="submit" type="submit" value="发送" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>
```

Event Handler to submit comment:

```
Template.reply_blackboard_post.events({
"submit .new-reply": function (event) {
    // This function is called when the new task form is submitted

    var text = event.target.comment.value;

    console.log('User information is ' + Meteor.user().username);
    Posts.update({_id: Session.get("blackboard_post_id")}, {$push:{
        replys:{username:Meteor.user().username,comment:text,createdAt:new Date()}}});
    event.target.comment.value="";
    document.getElementsByTagName("body").scrollTop=100000;
    return false;
  }
});
```

The command I deploy application is

```
meteor deploy travellers.meteor.com
```

After modification, I rerun:

```
meteor deploy travellers.meteor.com
```

I verified data through:

```
meteor mongo travellers.meteor.com

>db.post.find()
```

Comment: The old data won't be reset, you can safely redeploy your new code !

Comment: Hmm, seems not, I ran db.posts.find() before redeploy, I got
{ "_id" : "k5CoApQnXoCNurhWX", "createdAt" : .... 
Then I redeploy with meteor deploy, and run db.posts.find() after meteor mongo, I got nothing then.

Comment: Meteor deploy definitely does not delete your database. Can you list which commands you run that cause your data to be deleted, and maybe post your app code?

Comment: Sure, just updated the code.

Comment: You are right. There's bug in my code....